# Need a workaround for listing/adding Google Groups

Tags: google-apps, google-groups-api, google-groups-settings

My use case needs API to access (list, add and edit) a user's Google Groups. The only available thing I have is the APIs to [access and modify a Group's settings](http://My%20use%20case%20needs%20API%20to%20access%20(list,%20add,%20edit)%20a%20user's%20Google%20Groups.%20The%20only%20available%20thing%20I%20have%20is%20Google%20Group%20see%20https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups). This fulfils my "editing" needs but leaves me craving for "list" the groups and "add" a group APIs.

Is there a workaround so that I can list and add a Google Group? At worst, I need to have a call that can list me the email ids of the groups a user is part of.

Any help or alternatives is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please see [Admin SDK Directory Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For listing groups, I think you can use the [groups.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list)

HTTP request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups
```

If successful, this method returns a response body with the following structure:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#groups",
  "etag": etag,
  "groups": [
    [groups Resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups#resource)
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string
}
```

Read more on [Group Management](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_group) and [Group members](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members) for additonal reference.